# samba.cnf security parameter is not present in smb.conf

Tags: samba

The security = parameter is missing in the samba smb.conf file in Ubuntu 16.04.

Was the securty = paramiter removed from newer versions of Samba. I am probably just reading an old book. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: There is a typo in my question I wanted to set it to security=share not user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a config file from who knows what version,  but this post referenceses it.
http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/samba-in-14-04-broken/1301/2

I did not do any thing else mentioned in that thread other than use that smb.conf file. I did use the hosts allow = 192.168.0. Paramiter.  I also just ended up using users and not share.